# Drove with parking brake on

Tags: brakes

I only live like 5 miles from my school and my top speed was 60mph but the whole time I forgot I had my parking brake on. I noticed my truck wasn’t really driving right and it started to smell. I let it cool down while at a friends but my regular brakes weren’t working so good. Will it be ok to drive? I have a 2000 ford ranger

Answer (score 2):

In general the e-brake engages the rear brakes which are in general weaker than the front brakes and are quite likely drum brakes on your 2000 Ford Ranger. The smell was the stench of your rear brakes roasting.

It's possible that you have completely worn out your rear brakes or just enough that a simple adjustment is needed. If you've boiled your brake fluid then it should be flushed. If you got things hot enough to melt some rubber seals then you need to get it checked out.

If you only let the brakes cool for 20 minutes then that might not have been enough time; drum brakes retain heat longer. Let the car sit for 2 hours or more and see how the brakes feel. If you see brake fluid dripping on the ground near your tires then that is definitely a bad sign.

If you don't understand what I've said nor know how to check these issues nor have a mechanically inclined friend then be prepared to pay for new drum brakes if you take it to a shop and let them tell you what's wrong.